# Canada and US timezones PHP

Tags: php, yii

I want to display in a dropdown only the timezones in Canada and USA.
After some search, I tried to apply the `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US')`  It was cool, but It only return the US Timezones and not the canadian also tried to use `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US'|'CA')` It only returns *Pacific/Apia*.
And the `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::AMERICA)` returns the timezones from All americas.

Comment: Calculate the Canada's timezone yourself, using USA timezone.

Comment: `listIdentifiers(PER_COUNTRY)` only returns one country at a time, so call it twice and merge the results: `array_merge(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US'), DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'CA'));`

Comment: `|` only works with binary masks. If you binary-or the strings `'US'` and `'CA'` you get the new string `'WS'`, which is [Samoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa) (and its capital is Apia).

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried to do that, But im using Yii2 Active Form but that array merge dont work returns Undefined class constant 'PER_‌​COUNTRY'
the line is `'items' => array_merge(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_‌​COUNTRY, 'US'), DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'CA')),` I believe if it was pure PHP would work, its a good solution

Comment: `PER_COUNTRY` work after PHP 5.3.0. Check your php version.

Comment: @InsaneSkull
It works if I use only one datetimezone, but if I use the array merge it doesn't work

Comment: @MarkBaker Your solution worked. Can you give the answer so we can close this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was provided in the coment above

```
'items' => array_merge(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_‌​COUNTRY, 'US'), DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'CA'))
```